# Update all documents that matched a list of ids in one command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to update all documents that matched a list of id's in just one command.

Currently I have to loop each id to update

```
var ids = [
  "8007068113729",
  "8007068502622",
  "8007068505821",
  "0825646209804",
  "0880319084614",
  "4260041334885"
]

ids.forEach(function(i){
    db.listing.update({_id:i},{$set:{Supplier:'S'}});
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use the [`updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) method and the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

```
var ids = [
  "8007068113729",
  "8007068502622",
  "8007068505821",
  "0825646209804",
  "0880319084614",
  "4260041334885"
]

db.listing.updateMany({ "_id": { "$in": ids }}, { "$set": { "Supplier": "S" }});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use **$in** operator with **multi** flag as this :

```
var ids = [
  "8007068113729",
  "8007068502622",
  "8007068505821",
  "0825646209804",
  "0880319084614",
  "4260041334885"
]

db.listing.update({_id:{ $in: ids}},{$set:{Supplier:'S'}}, {multi: true});
```

Hope that help !